# Como utilizar dois parâmetros de data para dois Betweens sem repetir os parâmetros usando Spring Boots?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estou começando com o Spring Boot e estou tentando utilizar para uma consulta em que quero verificar se duas colunas data estão entre um período fornecido por parâmetros. O código abaixo funciona, porém para isso eu tenho que repetir os parâmetros (data início e data fim para comparação).

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
Collection<MyClass> findByDateBeginBetweenOrStartedWorkBetween (Instant firstDate, Instant lastDate, Instant firstDateAgain, Instant lastDateAgain);
```

Eu não achei nenhum exemplo similar até o momento. Eu imaginei que poderia ser algo parecido com o trecho abaixo:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
Collection<MyClass> findByDateBeginOrStartedWorkBetween (Instant firstDate, Instant lastDate);
```

Mas quando compilo o projeto, recebo o erro abaixo:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query
>   for method public abstract java.util.Collection
>   com...MyClass.findByDateBeginOrStartedWorkBetween
>   (java.time.Instant,java.time.Instant)! No parameter available for part
>   startedWork BETWEEN (2): [IsBetween, Between] NEVER.

Eu posso (e se sim, como eu posso) utilizar meus parâmetros de comparação apenas uma vez usando Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1):

O `between` conecta dois parâmetros, que não são reutilizáveis após a montagem interna da `query` pelo Spring. A mensagem de erro já dá essa dica a você:

> No parameter available for part startedWork

Quando a primeira parte da `query` é construída, os dois parâmetros que você passou são consumidos, logo, não restam mais parâmetros para a segunda parte da `query`, daí o erro.

Para seu problema, o uso do `@Query` deve resolver (um exemplo genérico, aplique-o ao seu caso específico):

```
Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Query(select x from MyClass x where x.firstDate between ?1 and ?2 and x.lastDate between ?1 and ?2)
Collection<MyClass> findByDatesBetween(Instant firstDate, Instant lastDate);
```

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela resposta. Sim a log já me mostra o cenário, tanto que contornei passando 2x cada data. Estou aguardando para ver se alguém mais responde, pois o intuito é ver se é possível tratar este cenário apenas usando a nomenclatura da consulta via spring boots. Caso ninguém se pronuncie, finalizarei com sua resposta como correta.